# INSERT INTO .. SELECT.. in stored procedure not working

Tags: mysql, select, insert, phpmyadmin

I am trying to perform an INSERT INTO .. SELECT .. statement in a stored procedure in phpmyadmin. The statement works perfectly when I run it as SQL, but when I use a stored procedure, it fails without giving an error message.

stored procedure:
IN: v_activation_code varchar 15 utf-8

```
INSERT INTO tbl_users (username, firstname, name, email, password, status, studnr, address, city, dob, gender)
SELECT username, firstname, name, email, password, status, studnr, address, city, dob, gender
FROM tbl_users_non_activated
WHERE activation_code LIKE 'v_activation_code'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide the body of stored procedure?

Comment: In phpmyadmin, this is what the stored procedure consists of. This is everything.

Comment: I don't think you want the v_activation_code in the SQL t obe in single quotes - if you do that it will only insert records where the activation code is that literal string.  Remove the single quotes and see if that helps.